# @Autowired between modules without explicit dependency in one direction

Tags: spring

I am currently starting with spring and am trying to implement a project, that has a hexagonal architecture. More specifically I orientate myself by an implementation from GitHub: https://github.com/mploed/ddd-with-spring.

Here I have a hard time understanding, how the communication between the application-service and the repositories (output-adapter module) is working. In the application-services module, the interfaces for the repositories are defined and then initialized by the service-application like this:

```
    @Autowired
    public ScoringApplicationService(ScoringResultRepository scoringResultRepository, AgencyResultRepository agencyResultRepository, ApplicantResultRepository applicantResultRepository, FinancialSituationResultRepository financialSituationResultRepository, ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
    this.scoringResultRepository = scoringResultRepository;
    this.agencyResultRepository = agencyResultRepository;
    this.applicantResultRepository = applicantResultRepository;
    this.financialSituationResultRepository = financialSituationResultRepository;
    this.applicationEventPublisher = applicationEventPublisher;
}
```

Now, the thing I don't understand about this is, that the classes, that implement these repository-interfaces, are in the adapters-output module, which application-services does not depend on. So how does the wiring work here? I tried to implement it in my own project, but wiring does not seem to work (as expected) and I do get a nullPointerException when I use the repositories in an application service.
How and why does it work in the GitHub example?

Thank you very much for answering!

Comment: It doesn't need to know. These are application services, which are used in an application and the application defines which adapters to use.

Comment: hm, ok. Thanks for the answer, I somewhat understand. Then my problem remains, that my repositories are null in the application-service. But if I understood it right, these should be initialized by the spring-application if I declare the JPARepository as (at)Component and the constructor of the application-service as @Autowired.  Do you have an idea, where the problem could be?

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. I didn't wire the application-service correctly in my rest controller and therefore dependency injection did not work properly. Thanks again for your answer. It seems small, but it definitely gave me a better understanding of how spring works.

Comment: They cannot be null, an autowired field or constructor has to fulfil its dependencies. If that doesn't happen you are instantiating things yourself. If they are still null, but in the debugger then you are looking at a proxy instead of the actual object.